# Missing data for column while trying to copy a csv file in a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have an issue trying to copy a CSV file in a table.
Here is my SQL statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nom_graph; 

CREATE TABLE nom_graph 
(
    DATE            VARCHAR(50),
    EDP_REC     FLOAT,
    EDP_EC      FLOAT,
    NB_KO       FLOAT
);
\copy nom_graph FROM '/home/giutools/EDP/out/SYNTHESE_RESYNC.csv' (DELIMITER('|')) 
;
```

and this is the error I get:

```
psql:nom_graph.sql:179: ERROR:  missing data for column "edp_rec"
CONTEXT:  COPY nom_graph, line 1: "DATE;EDP_REC;EDP_EC;NB_KO"
```

The CSV file is composed by a : date ; and all the other values are FLOAT.

I really can't understand what's the issue, been trying to solve it for two days now.

Comment: maybe try `(DELIMITER(';')` ?

Comment: OMG thank you !!!! it's working !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your CSV file,

Step1: Convert the excel file to CSV using http://www.zamzar.com .

Step2: Create table in postgresql with the same column that you see in your excel file.

Step3: Copy the CSV file to the already created table using below command,

```
copy table_name (column1,column2,..) from 'C:\Users\Public\lifile_name.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

Done, hope you find this helpful!